# The Basis of a set of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is just a general Linear Algebra question. I understand the concept of linear independence and spanning when it comes to general vector spaces. However I struggle to understand the same concepts when considering a set of transformations.

Particularly, if you wanted to prove that a set of linear transformations was linearly independent, how might you go about doing that? Generally speaking, a set $\{\mathbb{v}_1, \dots,\mathbb{v}_n\}$ is linearly independent if the only solution to 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n k_i\mathbb{v}_i = 0$$
is
$$k_1 = \dots = k_n = 0$$
But when it comes to linear transformations, how does this work exactly? Do you have to consider the image of the transformations, or the matrix representation of the transformations, or something else? For some reason I'm having a hard time conceptualizing this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088827/show-that-v-set-of-all-linear-transformations-from-v-to-r-is-a-vector Maybe this will help you.

Comment: This is actually pretty useful. I guess the general idea is to consider the image of the transformation acting on some general vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T_k:V\rightarrow W$, $1\leq k\leq n$ is a set of linear transformations over some field, then they are linearly independent if $$a_1T_1+\cdots a_nT_n=0$$ implies that $a_1=\cdots =a_n=0$. Here $a_1T_1+\cdots+a_nT_n=0$ is meant in the sense that $$(a_1T_1+\cdots+a_nT_n)(v)=a_1T_1(v)+\cdots+a_nT_n(v)=0$$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Right, so in general you should show that the properties are true for the result of the transformation acting on some general vector?

Comment: Yes, for linear independence of transformations, $v$ is taken as some general vector.

Comment: And in practice you get information about the $a_i$ by choosing various special values of $v$.